# Change eBook font doesn't change font for ordered/unordered lists

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, css, apple-books

I've created an ePUB with fonts exported so that when viewed on "Original" (eg in iBooks), you see the same font as the paperback edition of the book. But if you change the font in iBooks (eg to San Francisco), the text of the main body changes as expected. However, the font for ordered and unordered lists remains on "original." Is there a way to to edit the ePUB that when the font is changed by an eReader, it changes all the main text, lists included?

Comment: from what you wrote, it seems that CSS for ol and ul tags does not inherit the font for main text (that is, p tag). But to give a better answer, I need to know how you edited the ebook (and of course, its css file...)